# capybara - :9443 appears in the URL that I am visiting

Tags: https, capybara

I would like to visit a URL like https://latest.www.abc.com/def
However when I run it becomes https://latest.www.abc.com:9443/def

How can I omit the :9443 and be able to visit https://latest.www.abc.com/def exactly?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're only visiting external sites (not testing a local app) then set `Capybara.run_server = false`, which will stop Capybara from starting a server and trying to insert the port of that server into URLs.

If you are testing a local app and also need to visit external sites then make sure you haven't set `Capybara.always_include_port` to true (it defaults to false) OR explicitly specify the desired port in the visit command

```
visit('https://latest.www.abc.com:443/def')
```

Comment: Hi Thomas,
I have Capybara.run_server = false in my env.rb, I also tried to add Capybara.always_include_port = false but it still has :9443.
Thank you..

Comment: @user8750496 Then Capybara isn't inserting it.  You've either configured a proxy or the URL you're attempting to connect to is redirecting.

Comment: How can I verify please?

Comment: @user8750496 OR possibly you're using the rack_test driver (which can't visit external addresses at all) - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/tree/2.17_stable#drivers

Comment: @user8750496 Verify what?

Comment: my default driver is: Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
Also thatI needed to update host table in order to access the site, not sure if this affect

Comment: How can I check if I configured a proxy or the URL I'm attempting to connect to is redirecting? Thank you.

Comment: @user8750496  Start by going to the url in a browser and look at the network tab in the developer console to see what's actually happening.  You are actually trying to access an external site correct?  Your comment about having to update the host table makes me concerned you're not really sure what you're actually doing, or haven't correctly explained it.

Comment: I looked into the network tab but there are many items, what should I try to look for?

Comment: @user8750496 You'd be looking to see if the initial request is redirected (30x response code) - It seems you may benefit from reading up more on basic web development debugging.